# Ordinary Linear Inhomogeneous Initial Value Problem

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $J \subset \mathbb{R}$ be an open interval, $A: J\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, $w: J \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ continuous. Moreover, let $\Psi: J \rightarrow GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ be the fundamental matrix of the linear homogeneous equation
$$ x'(t) = A(t)x(t) \text{.}$$

Proof that the inhomogeneous initial value problem $x'(t) = A(t)x(t) + w(t), x(t_0) = x_0$ has the unique solution
$$ x(t) = \Psi(t) \left( \Psi(t_0)^{-1}x_0 + \int^t_{t_0} \Psi(s)^{-1} w(s) ds\right) \text{.}$$

---

It is easy to check that $x(t_0) = x_0$ (just plug it in and calculate), and while I didn't work on uniqueness yet, I believe that you can probably show the Lipschitz-condition and then applying Picard-Lindelof should give you the desired result.

I'm stuck here:

\begin{align}
x'(t) &= \Psi'(t) \Psi(t_0)^{-1} x_0 + \Psi'(t) \int^t_{t_0} \Psi(s)^{-1} w(s) ds + \Psi(t) \Psi(t)^{-1} w(t) \\
&= \Psi'(t) \Psi(t_0)^{-1} x_0 + \Psi'(t) \int^t_{t_0} \Psi(s)^{-1} w(s) ds + w(t) \\
&= A(t) \Psi(t) \Psi(t_0)^{-1} x_0 + A(t) \Psi(t) \int^t_{t_0} \Psi(s)^{-1} w(s) ds +w(t) \\
&= A(t) \Psi(t) \left(\Psi(t_0)^{-1} x_0 + \int^t_{t_0} \Psi(s)^{-1} w(s) ds\right) +w(t) 
\end{align}

because $\Psi'(t) = A(t) \Psi(t)$.

How do I proceed? Thanks a lot.

Comment: There is a typo in the formula of unique solution. There should be $x(t) = \Psi(t) \left( \Psi(t_0)^{-1}x_0 + \int^t_{t_0} \Psi(s)^{-1} w(s) ds\right)$. If you take this into account, you get the desired result

Comment: Ah, I'm incredibly stupid. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Well, for the sake of closure, I will just finish the last step. Since we had
$$
x(t) = \Psi(t) \left( \Psi(t_0)^{-1} x_0 + \int^t_{t_0} \Psi(s)^{-1} w(s) ds \right)
$$
we can just plug this into the last equation (this was the part that I somehow didn't see), and we get
$$
A(t)x(t) + w(t) \hspace{3cm} \left(= x'(t) \right)
$$
which is exactly the result we needed.

---

As for the uniqueness, one can show that inhomogenous linear differential equations satisfies the Lipischitz-condition and hence Picard-Lindelof applies.